# long click don't work with mouse in webview

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I made an android app with webview. If I do a long press with a tap, the contextual menu works perfect but I do it with a mouse no. Any idea?

I tried to override LongPress but it didn't work.

```
myWebView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (mMode == null)
                            return false;
                        else
                            mMode = startActionMode(mCallback);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Have you put `myWebView. setLongClickable(true);`?

Comment: yes, but it don't work.